# Apache Directory Studio on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to install Apache Directory Studio on my ec2 instance? Should I use something provided by AWS instead? The reason I want to do this to implement login for my springboot application. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe that Directory Studio is a set of tools for directory maintenance. It's not actually a directory service. You may be thinking of ApacheDS.

Comment: Ok but how to install on ec2. I cant find any documentation specific toec2

Comment: There are installers for Apache DS (https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/downloads.html) but I wouldn't expect to find any EC2-specific installation instructions.  You'll need to understand how to configure, at least, VPC, EC2, and Security Groups (all standard AWS services with plenty of documentation out there). That said, more generally, you should also validate that ApacheDS is actually a suitable solution for your needs (you haven't indicated anything specific so it's hard to advise here).